# How to translate heartbeat to soundwaves

Tags: mp3

I have my daughters heartbeat recorded on my phone. How can I get it translated into a physical soundwave strip that I can use for a tattoo/art?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Unless you're planning on writing a waveform visualizer, then you should be asking elsewhere.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about audio visualization

Comment: (You may find this site helpful: https://transloadit.com/demos/audio-waveform/generate-a-waveform-image-from-an-audio-file )

Comment: @Mrichards533: As Marc B said, Stack Overflow is the wrong site. You can try at [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/), they discuss all kinds of computer questions.

Comment: try matlab, it has those functions i believe. turn mp3 files as soundwave

Answer (score 1):

That's so cute.

I don't think it's a question for Stack Overflow but I'll give it an answer anyways.

What you need is a visual representation of the audio, not a physical.

A physical represantation would be made of matter which one could hold in his/her hands.

To make a visual represntation of the audio you woul'd need to open the audio file in a audio editing software.

Audacity is a simple and free tool: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Just load the audio file in Audacity, fiddle around with the audio-view until you see something you like, then hit PrintScreen on your keyboard (or PrtScrn or something like that), then go to Paint or similar image-editing software, go to Edit/Paste, and then cut out the piece of the image that you like, and then save it to an image file.

Hope that helps.